# Adding topology to PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, topology

I have installed PostGIS 2.0 and need new topology but it doesn't seem installed by default. I found a lot of command line to install PostGIS 2.0 with topology but is there a way just to add topology?

Answer (score 11):

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;
```

... like always, it is when you ask the question that you found the solution... I wasn't because of the installation but topology has to be activated for every database you want to use id with...